# How Can I Include Only Certain Source Files In Gradle

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I have a bunch of code in an Android Studio Project that was added from another project. When I originally added it, I wasn't ready to start using it so I researched how to *exclude* source files and added this to `build.gradle`:

```groovy
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            //needed until we integrate these classes
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Now I'm ready to start using some of these classes. What I'd like to do is specify individual files which should be *included*. Unfortunately the [include](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/tasks/util/PatternFilterable.html) statements don't seem to have any effect as gradle will still report that a certain package doesn't exist.

In fact it doesn't seem as though *include* does anything. I would have liked it to have the opposite effect of *exclude*. So that, if I change my config to only specify which files to *include*, only those are included. Sadly, this is not the case.

I've also tried being more explicite with my `exclude`'s and specifying 20+ packages which should be excluded and the individual classes I want included but it didn't work for me. Here's and example of that:

**EDIT: this has a bug in it, I didn't intend for `exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/**'` to be in there.** I also didn't need the includes while excluding explicitly. I shall post what finally worked in an solution.

```groovy
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            //needed until we integrate these classes
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/activities/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/adapters/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/application/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/database/**'
            include 'org/odk/collect/android/exception/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/external/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/listeners/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/Drive*'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/File*'
            include 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/FormControlle'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/FormDetails*'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/H*'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/P*'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/picasa/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/preferences/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/provider/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/receivers/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/tasks/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/utilities/**'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/views/A*'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/views/D*'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/views/E*'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/views/H*'
            include 'org/odk/collect/android/views/MediaLayout'
            include 'org/odk/collect/android/views/ODKView'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/views/T*'
            exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/**'
        }
    }
}
```

Now, I know you might wonder, *why even have all these files in the project in the first place? Why don't you just delete the unused ones and add them again when you're ready to implement them?* And the reason is that I want to keep the git history of these files intact so that features like `blame` and `annotate` properly attribute the code lines to their original author.

### Some other configurations which didn't work:

#### includes first, then exclude

```
include 'org/odk/collect/android/exception/**'
include 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/FormController.java'
include 'org/odk/collect/android/views/A*'
include 'org/odk/collect/android/views/MediaLayout*'
include 'org/odk/collect/android/views/ODKView*'
include 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/**'
exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/**'
```

example errors:

```
package org.odk.collect.android.logic does not exist
package org.odk.collect.android.exception does not exist
```

#### exclude first then includes

```
exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/**'
include 'org/odk/collect/android/exception/**'
include 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/FormController.java'
include 'org/odk/collect/android/views/A*'
include 'org/odk/collect/android/views/MediaLayout*'
include 'org/odk/collect/android/views/ODKView*'
include 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/**'
```

example errors:

```
package org.odk.collect.android.logic does not exist
package org.odk.collect.android.exception does not exist
```

Comment: Hold on, I think I've found the problem. I will confirm and then modify question and add answer.

Answer (score 4):

Just leaving this here for someone who might come along later. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417891/gradle-exclude-file-from-sourceset-not-working) shows how you can use `HashSet` to include just the files you need. So for instance, if you just wanted to include `FileA.java` and `FileB.java` and exclude everything else, you can use the following configuration:

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            setIncludes(new HashSet(['com/somepackage/FileA.java',
                                     'com/somepackage/FileB.java']))          
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Having an `exclude` for every class *not included* works. I haven't had any luck with includes. I would have preferred specifying only the files to *include* so if anyone knows how to do that, post another solution. I left my `include` statements there, but commented so it is more obvious which files I'm *not excluding*.

This is a quite verbose way of doing things. And I don't doubt there is a better way out there.

```
    sourceSets {
        main {
            java {
                //needed until we integrate these classes
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/activities/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/adapters/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/application/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/database/**'
//                include 'org/odk/collect/android/exception/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/external/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/listeners/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/Drive*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/File*'
//                include 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/F*'
//                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/FormDetails*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/H*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/logic/P*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/picasa/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/preferences/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/provider/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/receivers/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/tasks/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/utilities/**'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/views/Ar*'
//                include 'org/odk/collect/android/views/AudioButton'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/views/D*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/views/E*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/views/H*'
//                include 'org/odk/collect/android/views/MediaLayout*'
//                include 'org/odk/collect/android/views/ODKView*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/views/T*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/A*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/B*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/D*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/E*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/G*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/I*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/L*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/O*'
//                include 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/QuestionWidget'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/SelectMulti*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/SelectOneAuto*'
//                include 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/SelectOneWidget'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/Si*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/Sp*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/St*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/T*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/U*'
                exclude 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/V*'
//                include 'org/odk/collect/android/widgets/WidgetFactory'
            }
        }
    }
```