# Gradle exclude file from sourceSet not working

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've got a project where I'm trying to include a single file from a tree of java source files into a library project.  Whatever I do I am not able to include only that file.  I have had success in another project excluding all files except the one, but that only worked when running gradle from the library project only.  When it was run from the application directory, all files were included.  While trying to create a simple project that reproduces the issue, that same exclude all does not work either.

The sample file tree is simple:

```
application - android app that includes the two libraries
library1/
  build.gradle
  src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
library2/
  build.gradle
  src/main/AndroidManifest.xml
java/src/com/company/product/
  /pkg1
    Source1.java, Source2.java, Source3.java
    libraryoneonly/Library1Source.java
  /pkg2
    Source1.java, Source2.java, Source3.java
```

The library1 build.gradle looks like this.  Neither of the includes or excludes work below.

**library1/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
android {
    sourceSets {
        main.jni.srcDirs = []
        main.jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
        main.java {
            srcDir "../../java/src"
            exclude  {  FileTreeElement elem ->
                println "Searching for files, found: " + elem.relativePath
                !(elem.isDirectory() || elem.name.equals('Library1Source.java'))
            }
            //include ("**/libraryoneonly/**")
            //include ('com/company/product/pkg1/libraryoneonly/Library1Source.java')
        }
    }
dependencies {
    compile project(':library2')
}
```

And library2 build.gradle.  Surprisingly, the uncommented exclude below does work.

**library2/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
        sourceSets {
            main.jni.srcDirs = []
            main.jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
            main.java {
                srcDir "../../java/src"
                //exclude  {  FileTreeElement elem -> ((elem.path.contains('/libraryoneonly/')) ) }
                exclude ('com/company/product/pkg1/libraryoneonly/Library1Source.java')
            }
        }
```

Just to note, I never see the "Searching for files, found" text when library1 is building.  I'm not sure why.  I do see it in the larger project this test was modeled from, depending on where the build was run from.

If you'd like to pull the sample project and try it out, here is a link:  https://github.com/gbak/gradleTest

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally figured out the way to include a single file, without modifying the `srcDir` path:

```
main.java {
    srcDir "../../java/src"
    setIncludes(new HashSet(['com/company/product/pkg1/libraryoneonly/*.java']))
}
```

The path `'**/*.java'` is automatically included as an include, adding any more includes, like a direct include to the source file does nothing, since it is already included path anyway.

The `setIncludes()` call replaces any existing includes, including the `'**/*.java'` and sets the provided path[s] as the only include path.

Reading over the docs and adding the suggested printf statements after the main.java helped.

```
main.java.getIncludes().each { println "Added include: $it" }
main.java.sourceFiles.each { println "File in source set: " + it }
```

Thanks to all who have helped out.

Comment: You, have made my day. Thank you for posting this. It worked!

Answer (score 8):

Gradle'e SourceDirectorySet seems to be missing features. [docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/SourceDirectorySet.html) has a very telling note:

> TODO - configure includes/excludes for individual source dirs, and sync up with CopySpec TODO - allow add FileTree

The lack of features on par with CopySpec means there isn't a logical way to do what you're asking. The `include` pattern first adds a list of files to the sourceSet and then you can `exclude` a few files from that set. Except,

1. The `main.java` sourceset implicitly adds `**\*.java`
2. There is no *exclude everything that is not*

means you are SOL.

You can declare a separate `main.somethingElse` source set and use include just that one file, but I wasn't able to figure out how to add the new sourceset to the compile path. The hack suggested [here](https://discuss.gradle.org/t/how-do-i-add-a-single-file-to-a-java-sourceset/7407), using compiler args doesn't work anymore, java complains about invalid flags.

The only workaround I can think of is to use a path that excludes that files you do not want in `main.java.srcDir` for library1

```
    main.java {
        srcDir '../../java/src/com/company/product/pkg1/libraryoneonly'
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've tried the srcDir approach a while back and I remember there was some drawback, not allowing me to use it.  I recall even splitting the sources into separate packages to do that.  I'll have to try it again to refresh my memory.  The exclude everything does work in another project.

Comment: Did you have a chance to retry the srcDir approach?

Comment: Please note that the Android Gradle plugin does *not* use Gradle's default Source(Directory)Set, but its own [AndroidSource(Directory)Set](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceSet.html) implementation. So quoting the Gradle source code might not be valid here.

Comment: @sschuberth True, but [AndroidSourceSet](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/8701f80/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/AndroidSourceSet.groovy) and [AndroidSourceDirectorySet](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/build/+/6d7fd0d2eff092abf1aaf44d03756b24570b390c/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/api/DefaultAndroidSourceSet.java) just use the gradle implmentations underneath.

Comment: @RaGe - I tried changing the srcDir back to the package of the single desired file and the aar seems to be built correctly.  The classes.jar only has the one file and its package seems correct.  The entire app builds but I've yet to test the functionality through the app. Thanks

Comment: *>The exclude everything does work in another project.* You're excluding a single file in the other project, which is slightly different, and works as expected.

Comment: I recall now why I didn't change the srcDir to include the com.company.product, it screws up the package name on the file itself.  Since the file package includes com.company...  I now get an error on the package name.

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to be correct to me, it's just that [FileCollections](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/file/FileCollection.html) like [sourceFiles](https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceDirectorySet.html#com.android.build.gradle.api.AndroidSourceDirectorySet:sourceFiles) are lazily evaluated, i.e. your `println` statement is not executed until the contents of the source set are actually being requested.

Adding something like

```
main.java.sourceFiles.each { println "File in source set: " + it }
```

after the `main.java {...}` closure should actually make the `println` work.