# How to change .kt or .java files at compile time and build by .kt or .java builds

Tags: android, gradle, kotlin

Can we support .kt & .java files in same folder and in same package (if possible) and change my environment at build time for which files to build from?

Can we differentiate build in gradle on the basis of .kt or .java support?

Comment: on compile time AS generate same code as for java and kotlin so it's not an issue to keep both classes in same package

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to have .kt and .java files defining the same class and to choose which one will be used during the build? This *could* be achieved by excluding specific files as described in [Gradle exclude file from sourceSet not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39417891/gradle-exclude-file-from-sourceset-not-working). But it's a lot of work and would only lead to having to duplicate pretty much all changes, so it isn't clear why you'd want it in the first place.

But you don't need to do anything to "support .kt & .java files in same folder and in same package"; this is already supported by default. But they will be compiled together, so if you have the same class defined in .kt and in .java you'll get a compilation error just as if you defined it in two different .kt files.